# Problema com debug no android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Olá, estava debugando normalmente a aplicação no device, parei o debug fiz uma correção e quando voltei a acionar o debug recebi a seguinte mensagem:

```
Debug port (8700) is busy, make sure there is no other active debug connection to the same application
```

Porque isso acontece?
Como posso resolver?

Comment: Eu já tive esse problema e resolvi indo em **File > Invalidate Cache and restart!**

Comment: Isso resolveu, porque isso acontece no android studio vc sabe explicar?

Comment: @LeonardoDias, você respondeu a pergunta no comentário? Sabe como eu procedo neste caso?

Comment: Eu não sei explicar o motivo não, mas se tratando de Java+Android Studio, tudo pode acontecer kkkk

Comment: Não precisa marcar a resposta como certa não, caso alguém tenha o mesmo problema e acabe caindo na sua pergunta, vai ver os comentários aonde tem a solução